# How to make LinkedlList take only selected classes

Tags: java, interface, linked-list

I have interface CargoTransport and 2 classes, Truck and CargoShip implementing it. I want to create LinkedList in which I can put only this classes.

I tried to do it like this:

```
public class CargoDeliveryBase {
    private LinkedList<? extends CargoTransport> transports;

    CargoDeliveryBase(LinkedList<? extends CargoTransport> t) {
        transports.add(t.get(0));
        // or
        transport.add(new Truck());
    }
}
```

And compiler tells me "Required type: capture of ? extends CargoTransport" in this case

Comment: I tried it like this and this is still a bad idea I guess.
`public class CargoDeliveryBase <T extends CargoTransport> { }`

Comment: You should use a plain `LinkedList<CargoTransport>` here. Right now, the wildcard means that the elements are of *some type* that extends CargoTransport that you don't know. Therefore, the compiler cannot guarantee that `Truck` is of that mystery type

Comment: Thank you ;0 )))))
Have a great day

Comment: The definition of `transports` should be `LinkedList<CargoTransport>`. The definition of `t` in the constructor could be `LinkedList<? extends CargoTransport>` depending how you're going to use it. If you're going to assign it to `transports`, it has to be just `<CargoTransport>` but if you're going to copy the elements from it into `transports`, then it can be `<? extends CargoTransport>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just simply use `LinkedList<CargoTransport>`

Thanks to user, who answered in comments

Answer (score -1):

Create a super implementation of CargoTransport

`public interface Cargo {}`

`public interface CargoTransport extends Cargo {}`

Here goes your requirement:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class CargoDeliveryBase {
  private LinkedList<Cargo> transports;

  CargoDeliveryBase(LinkedList<? extends CargoTransport> t) {
    transports = new LinkedList<Cargo>();

      transports.add(new CargoShip());
      // or
      transports.add(new Truck());
      // or
      transport.add(t.get(0));
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a problem, but it's not why the OP's getting a compilation error about the type

Comment: @user sorry for my previous comment, just made it hastily. I think my modification will suffice the requirement.

Comment: This may work, but I don't see the point of `Cargo`. Just define `transports` as a `LinkedList<CargoTransport>`